# What to do if the "delete" key does not work on the computer?

Tags: windows, keyboard

The *delete* key on my keyboard does not work due to hardware failure. I am used to deleting (or Shift+deleting) files, folders and (less often) characters via this key. That being said, is there a way in Windows to use another key(s) on the keyboard with the very same functionality?

Comment: Keyboards are cheap. Why not get a new one? Unless this particular one is special, which I can understand. Is it possible that the keyboard is just dirty? Or maybe there's something stuck under the key like a paper clip?

Comment: @boot13, it is an [MSI ES500](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-in-Packaging-MSI-Star-Type-ES500-Black-Multi-Media-PC-Computer-Keyboard/141837448737?_trksid=p2047675.c100011.m1850&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140602152332%26meid%3Dddac4bfc8e3e41b19faec7c32124b4c7%26pid%3D100011%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26sd%3D141757122467) I bought second hand for less than 10 bucks and the delete key didn't work from the beginning, but it is the best I have had and is very convenient for typing, which I do a lot as part of my job.

Comment: get a new keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

1. Get AutoHotKey for your PC
2. Open a new notepad file
3. Type in the following code 
   F11::Send, {Del}
4. Save it as deleter.ahk (make sure save as is set to all files)
5. Put it in the startup folder of the start menu
6. Reboot

Now whenever you will press the F11 key, it will work like the delete key (it won't work with Shift + F11 (like Shift+Del))

Answer (score 1):

The following involve some not-entirely-trivial fiddling, but use only built-in functionality.

- Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator

  http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/tools/msklc.mspx
- Scan Code Mapper

  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj128267.aspx

   (scroll down to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`)